# Create a ActiveDataProvider based on ActiveRecord Relation in Yii2

Tags: yii, yii2

I have a many-to-many relation setup using a junction table in MySQL. Table Article is related to Activity via table Article_Activity.
In model Article I have a relation setup like this

```
public function getActivities()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Activity::className(), ['id' => 'activity_id'])
        ->viaTable('article_activity', ['article_id' => 'id']);
}
```

When rendering a view for one Article I would like to display a GridView of all Activities related to that Article.
The way most people seem to this is to create a ActiveDataProvider and insert a query into it that fetches related data but that feel a bit redundant since I have the relation setup in the model and there should be a way to get a dataprovider from that.

My question is: Is there a way to get a yii\data\ActiveDataProvider or yii\db\Query based on a instantiated models relation that can be used to display all related records in a GridView?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can actually call it like this:

```
$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
    'query' => $article->getActivities(),
]);
```

If you call the get method directly you get a `yii\db\ActiveQueryInterface` which is what you need to provide as `query` to the `ActiveDataProvider`.

When you call the `activities` attribute like `$article->activities` the `ActiveQueryInterface` is executed and you get the records from the query results.

Comment: The thing is, when you call it like an attribute, Yii2 makes it so the query gets executed and returns the actual query result to you, while if you call the method directly you get the query object.

Comment: I´m sorry.. deleted my stupid comment just when you answered. You wrote it in correctly in your solution. Thanks for your time!

Comment: Is this still correct? Trying it in 2.0.36 I'm getting an error: `Calling unknown method: yii\db\ActiveQuery::getModels()`

Answer (score 0):

Based on you Article model you have  the activities relation that get multiple  Activity related  to  you Article

a normal dataProvider  like

```
  $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
      'query' => Article::find()->joinWith(['activities'])->
              where(['your_column'=> $your_value]),
  ]);
```

return activeRecord  whit also the related  activities

you can refer to the related  models inside the dataProvider

```
$models = $dataProvider->models; // this is a collection of model related to the dataProvider  query 
                                 // so the firts model is  $model=models[0]
```

then for each of this you can obtain acyivities

```
 $activities = $model->activities;
```

or value

```
 $my_activity_field = $model->activities->my_activity_field
```

Comment: Thank you but I´m not sure this answers my question. What I want to do is to use the relation setup in my model to avoid writing a redundant query whenever needing a data provider.